# Is It possible to segue to a specific view controller from another storyboard

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, segue, uistoryboardsegue

Within my app i have 2 storyboards, one has all the configuration screens and the other has the main screens of the app.

In one of the main screens of the app the user can press a button which allows them to go back and edit or add anything to the configuration.

The issue is if the user came from the main screens, once they press the done button on the configuration screen to confirm their changes, is there a way i can segue back to the main screen storyboard and then segue to the screen they were previously on before going to configuration ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have code to transition between the storyboards.

```
- (IBAction)showNextStoryboard:(id)sender
{
    UIStoryboard *nextStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"SecondStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *nextRoot = [nextStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController];
    [self presentViewController:nextRoot
                       animated:YES
                     completion:^{}];
}
```

And to return:

```
- (IBAction)returnToPreviousStoryboard 
{
    [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{}];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yeah i have all my code for transitions between storyboards. My issues was once i transition back to the main storyboard, how do i get it to automatically segue back to the screen the user was at before going into configuration. This needs to happen without any button clicks

Comment: @Fernando, this code should take you back to the controller that you were in before you switched to the other storyboard. It just presents another controller over your current one -- it doesn't matter whether that presented controller is in another storyboard or not. When you dismiss, you go back to the controller that did the presentation.

Comment: So it does, thanks very much! that works for this now. Thanks for all your help